# How do I create a view following the player in a JavaFX game?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to make my first game in JavaFX, where a player object (not a Node) will move inside a level. However, the full level shouldn't be visible inside the window, only a part of it surrounding the player should be. I've searched quite a bit for a solution to this that works with the way I've done my project, but haven't been successful. The following code describes how I've set up my GUI:

```
private VBox appRoot;
private Pane gameRoot;
private Canvas canvas;
private GraphicsContext gc;
private HBox uiRoot;
```

This is the different panes I use. The appRoot contains both the gameRoot and the uiRoot, in that order. The gameRoot contains the canvas. Everything inside the level, including the level itself, is drawn onto the canvas, like this:

```
canvas = new Canvas(ROOM_WIDTH, ROOM_HEIGHT);
gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
createLevel(ROOM_WIDTH, ROOM_HEIGHT, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT);
gc.scale(2, 2);
drawLevel(gc, ROOM_WIDTH, ROOM_HEIGHT, CELL_WIDTH, CELL_HEIGHT);
player.render(gc);
```

createLevel and drawLevel just creates a level and draws squares where different blocks should be. The player object's render method draws the player at its x- and y-coordinates. As you can see I've scaled the canvas, so as of now the entire level isn't shown when the game is started.

The problem is that I can't make it so that what is shown in the window is the things surrounding the player object. I've seen some code utilizing the methods setLayoutX and setLayoutY, but I've been unable to reproduce this so that it works.

I would be very grateful if anybody could help me out with this, and hopefully without changing too much of how the drawing is done.

Thanks! :)

Also, here are two pictures showing how it looks; the first is when the player is not inside the current view, and the second is with the player in the view.

[Image without player in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8K01.png)

[Image with player in view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElCkW.png)

Comment: if gc works like g2d, you would just use gc.translate(xCoord, yCoord)

Comment: @MitchWeaver That did something to it, but the screen just turned white. I used the player object's x and y when doing this. I'm assuming the level moved to a weird position, but I don't know what's going on really.

Comment: To me it looks like what you want to achieve with the scaling is to have a viewport on the level instead of showing the whole level. Is that correct?

Comment: @hotzst Yes, exactly! And it should follow the player object as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not us the `Canvas` directly to display the level. Instead you can use an image that represents your level and then have the image in an [`ImageView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html). On that [`ImageView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/ImageView.html) you can define a viewport of the area of the image that is visible.

To get the image you can either use your `Canvas` node and take a snapshot (See this [question](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2450090?tstart=0)). This is probably the easiest way with what you have. Or you can forego the `Canvas` altogether and draw the image. If the levels are predefined (and not generated at runtime), this seems the best approach, then you can supply the images as resources along with the code.

Comment: Ok, I managed to create a functioning view by doing this! Thank you! :D

However, the quality of the graphics was greatly reduced, looks like some anti-aliasing. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Hard to say without any concrete code example. My guess is it might be something with scaling or taking a snapshot. I suggest you ask a separate question for this issue along with some code.